# Appropriate choice of stop sign for file that I'm reading with java file I/O

Tags: java

I'm going to make a Java program that takes an object and writes it to a text file, so that it can then read it in and recreate the object again when I restart the program. The file will be structured like this:

```
<docID> <score> <positions> <docID> <score> <positions> ...
```

`docID` can only range from 0 to about 17 000. So a fixed length of 5 characters will do the job for now. `score` will only range from 0 to 99, so two characters will do. But `positions` is more tricky. It will be a list of integers, where each integer will be separated by a space. But I can't know how many entries the list will have. So I think I need some sort of stop sign. My question is therefore, what is an appropriate sign for this job? I'm thinking that some common stop signs such as `\0` will interfere with Java's file I/O. Could someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: If you want to give a character a special meaning you just need to make sure that regular occurrences of that character in your data set get **escaped**. If you escape all other occurrences in a pre-processing step, every character will be fine.

Comment: Why not use an already existing file structure for text-readable serialization such as XML (JAXB) or JSON? This way you can leverage already existing libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are developing your own file format. Before we get into things you can do in your own file format, it might also be worth looking at existing formats like JSON and XML. These allow you to be very extensible (future-compatible) and mean you don't have to worry about about the low-level details of parsing code.

Here are a few other ideas:

- Each "record" goes on its own line, which would mean that your "record separator" would be a newline (`\n`)
- You could quote each set of `position`s so that at the end of the quoted section, you know you are on to the next line

Just as an example, using JSON and Jackson as the JSON serializer, your code could look something like this (note: this is from memory, I haven't actually run/tested this):

```
public class Document {
    int docId;
    int score;
    List<Integer> positions
}

public class DocumentSet {
    List<Document> documents;
}

public class RecordSet {
    List<DocumentSet> records;
}

String saveRecords(RecordSet rs) {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); // ...
    return om.writeValueAsString(rs);
}
```

You will end up with something that looks like this (though potentially much more compact):

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "documents": [
                {
                    "docId": 123,
                    "score": 75,
                    "positions": [11, 99, 83129, 3, 1347]
                },
                {
                    "docId": 12,
                    "score": 93,
                    "positions": [4561, 465, 1]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

A format like JSON saves you from worrying about a few things:

- Future extensibility - You can add additional fields and old readers will still be able to understand the files (they just ignore fields they don't understand)
- Escaping - You never know when you'll need to accept something like an arbitrary text string. JSON (and XML) both have built-in ways of dealing with special characters (like spaces, newlines, backslashes, quotes, etc...) that you might also find in your data. You *can* come up with your own method of escaping, but someone else has already figured it out for you
- Interoperability - JSON (and XML) are pretty universal formats with many libraries in every imaginable programming language. If you ever need to read or write one of these documents from a different language, you won't have to re-implement all of your low-level parsing logic

Once common concern with JSON size. It's usually not an issue (space is cheap) but you can always GZip your data on-the-fly and it becomes pretty compact.

Comment: That's good, but I forgot to mention that the line I've posted in my example file is only one of many. So each line is a record with many `<docID> <score> <positions>` in sequence. Would it work to combine your two suggestions so that I use the `\n` like I've explained just now, and the quotes for each `<positions>`?

Comment: Sure, that could work. You could also use other characters like colons between records on the same line. I'd avoid NULL (`\0`) if you are building a human-readable text format, since text editors (and humans) won't handle those very well.